# IIS Linux Account

Tags: sql-server, linux, vb.net, iis-7

We have a web services which runs on a **windows server** and we have images hosted on a **Linux server** (NAS Box). What we need to do is allow a **VB.NET** web service to write to the **Linux server**.

I understand that you have to grant the application pool access rights to the machine but I cant see any way to do this.

We are simply writing a byte array. At the moment we have granted everyone `full rights` but we still get the exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\****Some
>   Directory****' is denied.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is the windows server a virtual machine? Does it have to write on a linux shared folder?

Comment: Its a windows server but I am afraid I don't really understand the other part.